# Why are there no mousewheel events fired in Edge when using a Surface Pro 3 Type Cover

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

I'm not getting any mousewheel events in Microsoft Edge when scrolling a overflown div with a Surface Pro 3 Type Cover. Is this an Edge bug?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/achqzgLL/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scroll").on("mousewheel wheel", function(){
        alert("scroll");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: how are you scrolling? mouse plugged into the usb port? or dragging a finger on-screen?

Comment: Edge isn't stable yet, my assumption would be that this is a bug.

Comment: I've just tested your JSFiddle and it fires the scroll event when I use the two-finger scroll gesture on the Type Cover. This was tested in the latest public build (20.10240.163840).